# Python multiprocessing memory error

Tags: python, multiprocessing

I'm using map_asyn to share my work load, however I'm finding that I'm getting a `MemoryError`, but I'm not finding a solution or a work around. Here is the error I get:

```
Exception in thread Thread-3:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 810, in __bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "C:\Python27\lib\threading.py", line 763, in run
    self.__target(*self.__args, **self.__kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\lib\multiprocessing\pool.py", line 380, in _handle_results
    task = get()
MemoryError
```

Here is the code:

```
pool = Pool(maxtasksperchild=2)
fixed_args = (targetdirectorytxt, value_dict)
varg = ((filename,) + fixed_args for filename in readinfiles)
op_list = pool.map_async(PPD_star, list(varg), chunksize=1)
while not op_list.ready():
        print("Number of files left to process: {}".format(op_list._number_left))
        time.sleep(600)
op_list = op_list.get()
pool.close()
pool.join()
```

Here is what I have tried:

- Reducing the number of threads
- Limiting maxtasksperchild
- appply_sync instead of map_sync

Are there anymore suggestions to avoid this error?

I'm reading in the file with:

```
with open(os.path.join(txtdatapath,pathfilename), "r") as data:
        datalines = (line.rstrip('\r\n') for line in data)
        for record in datalines:
```

Comment: You're running out of memory - it's probably not just the number of threads but what the threads do. It seems like you are processing files. If they are too big to fit in memory, make sure you're not reading the full files but read them line by line or X bytes at a time instead.

Comment: @AndréLaszlo Yes, that might be the issue. But need a smarter way to read in files. I put how I'm doing it in the question, but this still causes memory issue.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @AndréLaszio, it is likely that the files are too large to be kept in memory. Altering your logic to only keep one line in memory at a time should alleviate the memory pressure unless each line is also huge.

Here is an alternate approach to opening the file and working with one line at a time. Keeping the file contents available in memory as an array is an expensive operation.

`readingfiles.py`:

```
from memory_profiler import profile


@profile
def open_file_read_all_then_parse(filename):
    """
    Open a file and remove all the new lines characters from each line then
    parse the resulting array of clean lines.
    """
    with open(filename, "r") as data:
        datalines = (line.rstrip('\r\n') for line in data)
        for record in datalines:
            pass


@profile
def open_file_read_and_parse(filename):
    """
    Open a file and iterate over each line of the file while striping the record
    of any newline characters.
    """
    with open(filename, "r") as data:
        for record in data:
            record.rstrip('\r\n')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    # input.dat is a roughly 4m file with 10000 lines
    open_file_read_all_then_parse("./input.dat")
    open_file_read_and_parse("./input.dat")
```

I used an additional module to help track down my memory usage, the module is named [memory profiler](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/memory_profiler). This module helped me verify where my memory issues were coming from and may be useful for your debugging. It will list out memory usage of a program and the area the memory is being used.

For more in depth performance analysis I recommend [this article](http://www.huyng.com/posts/python-performance-analysis/) by Huy Nguyen.

Comment: I cannot get the profiler working correctly on the windows platform. How does the logic for opening the file, differ from what I have above?

Comment: Sorry I am mistaken, I thought this line `datalines = (line.rstrip('\r\n') for line in data)` was looping over each line and saving them in `datalines` as an array. With further inspection I see it is a `generator` type in python 2.7 (probably all versions too). You are correct, both approaches should give the same results.